# hybrid-π model VS T-Model for MOSFET and BJT

Tags: mosfet, bjt

1) when to use T model for MOSFETs instead of hybrid-π model?
2) when to use T model for BJT's instead of hybrid-π model?

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend **NOT** to use the T-model. I hesitate to classify it as "wrong" - but very close! At least it is confusing - unless you know exactly what you are doing. However, anybody who does exactly know what he is doing does not need any such model at all.

**Explanation/justification:**

(1) The transconductance gm appears as a resistor r=1/gm between the base node and the emitter node. This is not in accordance with physical reality because gm is a TRANSconductance and connects input voltage and output current. Hence - it must not be modeled as a resistor (two-pole element).

(2) Looking into the model from the emitter (base at ground) the input resistance is 1/gm (correct); however, looking into the model from the base node (common emitter) it seems that the input resistance also is 1/gm - but this is wrong!

(3) In case of common emitter topologies, the model is valid for current injection into the base only (current source at the base node). This is not in accordance with most of the applications which use signa VOLTAGES.

(4) In case of emitter degeneration (Resistor RE in the emitter path) we have two resistive parts in series: r=1/gm and RE. Consequently, the denominator of the gain formula contains the sum (r+RE). This expression can be misinterpreted because one might think that both parts play the same role (e.g. feedback). But, of course, that is not the case.

(5) My conclusion: I do not like the T-model at all. For my opinion, it does not help to understand what`s going on within a transistor - the contrary is true! Hence, I cannot see one single advantage of this model if compared with the classical (pi and h) small-signal models.

Answer (score 0):

In more than 20 years working with BJTs and MOSFETs I've never heard about the T-model. So I googled it and found [this lecture](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/412/handouts/5.6%20Small%20Signal%20Operation%20and%20Models/The%20Hybrid%20Pi%20and%20T%20Models%20lecture.pdf).

Where it says: *The Hybrid-Π and the T circuit models are equivalent—they both will result in the same correct answer!*

Ergo: There's no difference, you can use **whatever you prefer**.

Comment: yes that's true, but there are situations where the T model makes the analysis faster, easier and cleaner, i'm looking for these situations

Comment: I cannot find examples in those lectures. You could just take the 3 basic circuits, commons emitter/base/collector and evaluate all 3 with Hybrid-Pi and T models and see what **you** prefer. I would not expect miracles in efficiency by using one or the other model.

Comment: John Jack - me too. I am also looking for "these situations". Up to now - I know only disadvantage of this unrealistic model.

Answer (score 0):

I was taught that the common base configuration is easier to analyze with the T model; CC or CE is usually easier with hybrid-π, and for anything else, you might as well sketch both versions and see what looks simpler.

There are definitely circuits that are a lot easier with the T model, but whether they exist outside of contrived homework problems, I don't know.

Comment: I don`t agree. I cannot see any reason why analyses based on the T-model could be "easier". Can you show which circuits are "definitely" a lot easier to analyze?

Comment: @LvW, as I said in my answer, common base configuration tends to be easier. Compare hybrid-pi and T for CB with emitter degeneration. The base being held at ground means you can essentially ignore the collector "arm" of the T model: i_e = v_e / (r_e + Re) is obvious by inspection, but I'd probably need some paper to work the same thing out for the pi model.

Comment: As to "circuits that are 'definitely' easier", I remember a few extremely nasty sedra & smith problems (mostly consisting of a large number of CB bjts connected together), but I don't have them on hand.

Comment: In Sedra&Smith: Hybrid-Pi model is used in:  CS and CE. The T model is used in:CS with a sourcre Resistance and CE with and emitter resistance,CG and CB, CD and CC.